# What happens to the group structure of an elliptic curve over a field when the discriminant = 0?

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, discriminant

Working on a question for a number theory class.

So, basically, it asks us what happens to the group structure of an elliptic curve over a field if the discriminant is equal to zero?

So, basically, what I've got is that either is crosses itself, or it ends up having a cusp. In either case, it does not have a well defined derivative at some point. Since lambda depends on a well defined derivative, if an elliptic curve has a singular point at (a, b), then elliptic curve addition would not be well defined for (a, b) + (a, b).

Is this right? Am I missing something else that happens to group structure?

EDIT: I guess, also, when they are this shape, we couldn't guarantee that a tangent line that intersected the line in two places intersected it in a third place. So, then, the operations aren't necessarily well defined anywhere? Is that more right?

Comment: Do you mean discriminant?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Super tired. Haha. Edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

If the discriminant is zero, it's not an elliptic curve. Anyway,
consider an singular irreducible plane cubic curve $C$ over an algebraically
closed field.

A singular irreducible cubic has one singular point. The
non-singular points on the curve do have a group structure though. When $C$
has a node, the group of non-singular points is isomorphic to
the multiplicative group
$K^*$ and when $C$ has a cusp, the group is isomorphic to the additive
group of $K$.

You can find details in texts such as Silverman's.